# Does anyone know of a good video library script?

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, cots, video-gallery

Our company now has over 40 tutorial videos and I'm looking for a video gallery app.

Something that would be similar to:
http://tv.telerik.com/
or
http://umbraco.org/documentation/videos/for-site-builders/datatypes/using-datatypes-that-have-prevalues

**Does anyone know of any PHP or asp.net solutions?**

I'd rather not re-invent the wheel.
As there are a ton of hidden functions like sorting, most popular, tagging, comments, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use any popular CMS. For WordPress, here is what you can do. You can use many of it's out of the box features -

- each video is created as a blog-post. So u have comments, tags too.
- each blog-post will have a custom parameter as video url
- while rendering a single post, take this custom parameter and build HTML/embded video object with your flash player.
- these blogposts can be moderated my multiple wordpress users
- comes with plenty of free themes to choose. Enjoy!
- customize the archive page, to have a thumbnail like gallery page.
- use a [ratings plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=ratings) to rate blog-posts.

For now onwards, start thinking of customizing a CMS rather reinventing :)

- Ankit

Comment: ... and here's what I made: http://www.simpletick.com/video/
It was faster just to create a few tables and make it from scratch.
disqus - works as a great plugin for comments
google analytics - works well for keeping track of what's popular

Comment: so you did not use Wordpress :(. WP might have rocked you! Btw, use of disqus is good.